# show php json data using json_decode

Tags: php, json

I have this json data:

```
["warm","cold"]
```

I need to show json data using this function:

```
function typeid($id){

    $arr = json_decode($id , true);

    foreach ($arr as $k=>$v){
        $type = $v.' - '; 
    }

    return $type;
}
```

result is (only one result):

```
cold -
```

how do can I show all json data with `-`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$type` must be an array:

```
foreach ($arr as $k=>$v){
    $type[] = $v; 
}
$result = implode('-', $type); //implode it
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your code with this :

```
$type = '';
foreach ($arr as $k=>$v){
    $type .= $v.' - '; 
}
```